# Connection refused from MySQL runtime in Eclipse Che

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, eclipse-che

I'm trying to connect to a db in a MySQL runtime from another NodeJS runtime in a [multi-machine workspace](https://www.eclipse.org/che/docs/tutorials/multi-machine/).

In a test I'm calling the API `http://localhost:3000/target` with the list of target users. Code in this API runs a SELECT on the db:

```
...

exports.list = function(req, res) {

    req.getConnection(function(err, connection) {

        if (err) {
                console.log("MySQL " + err);
        } else {

              connection.query('SELECT id FROM target', function(err, rows) {

            if (err) {
                console.log("Error Selecting : %s ", err);
            } else {

                ...
```

The result I get from terminal:

```
get target list from http://localhost:3000/target
MySQL Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
```

Here I define the connection to the db:

```
var express = require('express');
var connection = require('express-myconnection');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var config = require('config');
var connectionConfig = config.get('mysql');
var connectionInstance = connection(mysql, connectionConfig, 'request');

...

app.use(connectionInstance);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Welcome');
});

app.get('/target', target.list);

....
```

config:

```
{
    "mysql": {
        "host": "localhost",
        "user": "[user]",
        "password": "[password]",
        "database": "[database]"
    },
    "app": {
        "port": 3000,
        "server": "http://localhost"
    }
}
```

This is what I have in the configuration of the db machine in Eclipse Che:

[snapshot of servers configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjUTw.png)

Here's my recipe:

`services:
  db:
    image: eclipse/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: petclinic
      MYSQL_USER: petclinic
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_ROOT_USER: root
    mem_limit: 1073741824
  dev-machine:
    image: eclipse/node
    mem_limit: 2147483648
    depends_on:
      - db
  elasticsearch:
    image: florentbenoit/cdvy-ela-23
    mem_limit: 2147483648`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you share your `recipe` for the multi-machine workspace? That would help a lot in debugging it.

Just a guess: I think the problem with your setup is the use of `localhost` for your db connection. If you are running a multi-machine setup, the db is running in a different docker container and needs to be addressed by its name.

Excerpt from the Multi-Machine Tutorial:

> In the recipe the depends_on parameter of the “dev-machine” allows it
>   to connect to the “db” machine MySQL process’ port 3306. The
>   “dev-machine” configures its MySQL client connection in the projects
>   source code at src/main/resources/spring/data-access.properties. The
>   url is defined by jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://db:3306/petclinic which uses
>   the database machine’s name “db” and the MySQL server default port
>   3306.

You need to configure the open ports in your `recipe`.

**Disclaimer:** I am not directly affiliated with Eclipse Che, Codenvy or Red Hat, but we are building our [own cloud IDE for C/C++ multicore optimization](https://slx.cloud) on top of Eclipse Che.

Comment: as you can see from my recipe I added in my question, there's the 'depends_on' parameter to let the dev machine connect to the db machine. Do I have to do something more?

Comment: yes, you need to change your configuration file to use the `db` machine instead of localhost: `{
    "mysql": {
        "host": "db"
    }
}`

Comment: It works! I thought mapping localhost and real ports to eclipse che hostnames and ports was a matter of workspace configuration, without touching the actual application code. Instead in the configuration file of the app I had to change 'localhost' to 'db', as you suggested.

Comment: Glad to hear that!